# check inheritance of dynamic types of 2 variables - but they are undeclared in scope

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, incomplete-type

Is it possible to check inheritance between underlying type (e.g. `B` and `C`) of 2 variables (e.g. `b` and `c`) if both are not declared in the scope?

I think this is impossible, but I am not sure.

**Test1.h:-**

```
#include <vector>
class A{};
std::vector<A*> test1();
```

**Test1.cpp:-**

[image]

```
#include "Test1.h"
class B : public A{};
class C : public B{};
class D : public A{};
std::vector<A*> test1(){
    A* b=new B();     A* c=new C();     A* d=new D();
    std::vector<A*> re;  
    re.push_back(b);  re.push_back(c);  re.push_back(d);
    return re;
}
```

**Test2.cpp** ; Note that, `B` `C` `D` are not known here (by design):-

```
#include "Test1.h"
int test2(){
    std::vector<A*> v=test1();
    A* b=v[0];  A* c=v[1];  A* d=v[2];
    isInherit(b,c); //true
    isInherit(c,d); //false
    isInherit(b,d); //false
}
```

If the answer is yes, please show how to code `bool isInherit(A* base,A* derive){}`.

Note that modifying `class A` is not allowed.
(Thus, a hack to set a `non-static field of A` = `a value depending on type` is not allowed.)

I may use it as some kinds of black-magic inside my code.

Comment: I don't understand how your types are incomplete. In your example, your types are defined. If you forward declare your types instead, then you cannot specify any inheritance.

Comment: @François Andrieux  At `Test2.cpp` : `B` `C` `D` are incomplete.  (wrong?)

Comment: An [incomplete class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type) has a specific meaning in c++. It indicates a class that has been declared but not defined. In `Test2.cpp` none of `B`, `C` or `D` have been declared.

Comment: @François Andrieux Oh, what should I call it, then?  I should change title to "are not declared"?

Comment: I don't know of a technical term to describe a class that is not yet been declared in a given context, but I would assume most developers would understand "undeclared".

Comment: @François Andrieux Thank a lot, I have edited all related part.

Comment: The correct technical term, I think, would be "[the dynamic type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Dynamic_type) of a polymorphic object" (assuming `A` is, in fact, polymorhic). You can compare them for equality, via `typeid`; but I can't think of any way to check whether one is inherited from another.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik   Thank!  It is useful (edit again).   If the answer is no, then I got a complete satisfying answer.

Comment: `Test2.cpp` doesn't even know about the types `B` `C` or `D`. How would it ask about classes that it doesn't even know about? What would be the point?

Comment: @cdhowie It is useful for some quick-and-dirty assertion.  There are still other ways around, but I want to know whether this way is a dead-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of.

It requires `virtual bool A::baseOf(A const* derived) const = 0` and `bool B::baseOf(A const* derived) const override { return dynamic_cast<B*>(derived); }`

This now allows you to check `foo->baseOf(bar)` when all you have is the definition of A.

Things do break down if `C` forgets to override `B::baseOf`.

Comment: Hacker!   You push the envelope of my rule. +1

Comment: If only modification of `Test2.cpp` is allowed, it is impossible, right?

Comment: Indeed. My idea is built on the notion that each class knows its own type even if `Test2.cpp` does not.